# Can someone please explain to me a complicated function pointer type in C++

Tags: c++, types, function-pointers

Can anyone tell me what is the type of the parameter for the function `f`?

```
int f(void (*(int,long))(int,long)) {}
```

I am getting a similar type to this in when trying to compile some variadic template heavy code (my own wrapper around `std::thread`)...

Comment: this kind of code should always be a part of C/C++ obfuscation contests. use a typedef.

Comment: @vsoftco - I get this from a compiler error

Comment: @Brian - Try it in C++.

Comment: Run it through `cdecl` with 'explain'. There's an online one somewhere.

Comment: There's a parenthesis missing at the end, at least. Is this copy-pasted or retyped off the screen? If the latter, please copy&paste. The signature does not make a lot of sense with an added closing paren because it would declare a function taking a function (rather than a function pointer) argument, which I would not expect to see in compiler output.

Comment: I switched to a simpler version (Note: I'm simplyfing the compiler output since it contains lots of templated class which are of no interest to me)

Comment: That may be the case, but you're losing important information on the way. I'd have expected this to be of the form `int f(void (*(*)(int, long))(int, long))` or so.

Comment: @Wintermute - let me rephrase the question. The function I wrote above compiles with gcc, I want to know why.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it's just unexpected to see in compiler output because it uses a syntax exception.

Comment: @Wintermute you're right, i trusted cdecl instead of using my brain. And I wouldn't call it an exception

Comment: Well, can anyone tell me in english what this type means? Without the first `(int,long)` it would be a function pointer to a function that accepts an int and a long, but with it I don't understand...

Comment: @Wintermute *"There's a parenthesis missing at the end, at least"* Not sure what you mean. I used the original version from the OP history, and it's all balanced: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0238570633c653bd

Comment: Oh, did I miscount? It appears so; my bad. Headspinning stuff, this.

Comment: @dyp: That is a really cool technique but it didn't quite work right.

Comment: @MobyDisk What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Here, have a fishing lesson: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: @dyp: The output says "function taking (pointer to function taking (pointer to int, pointer to function taking (long, ) and returning void, int, long, ) ..." but the function does not return a "void, int, long."  Maybe it just needs a closing paren after "returning void" to show that is the end function.

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ is nice to have

Comment: @MobyDisk Ah, ok, so it's not wrong, but unclear: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db96acb238237a59

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The declaration

```
int f(void (*(int,long))(int,long)) {}
```

declares a function `f` returning `int` and taking as argument a pointer to a function that takes `int, long` parameters and returns a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes parameters `int, long`. Using a typedef for the innermost function pointer, this becomes more readable:

```
typedef void (*fptr)(int, long);
int f(fptr(int, long));
```

Or with a named parameter,

```
int f(fptr handler(int, long));
```

This is perfectly valid code, but it is odd to see in compiler output because it uses a special syntax rule: in a function parameter list, a function type declarator declares a function pointer parameter. That is to say,

```
int f(fptr   handler (int, long)); // is equivalent to
int f(fptr (*handler)(int, long));
```

...and you'd expect the compiler to use the lower, general form.

Comment: *"This is perfectly valid code, but it is odd to see in compiler output because it uses a special syntax rule"* Does this appear somewhere in (a revision) of the OP or just in your example?

Comment: @dyp `int f(void (*(int,long))(int,long)) {}` uses the function type; the pointer version would be `int f(void (*(*)(int,long))(int,long)) {}`

Comment: OP mentions that it's in compiler output in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 13):

It's a function taking a pointer to a function that takes `int` and `long` as parameters and returns a function taking `int` and `long` as parameters and returns `void`. Probably a lot clearer if you use a trailing return type and name the function:

```c++
int f(auto g(int, long) -> void (*)(int, long));
```

Answer (score 6):

In the function declaration

```
int f(void (*(int,long))(int,long));
```

obfuscated form of function pointer is used. Let's start with basic to understand this code.

```
void (*f_ptr)(long);
```

declares `f_ptr` as a pointer to a function that expects a `long` parameter and returns nothing.

As a parameter of a function this function pointer can be declared as

```
int f1( void f_ptr(int) );
int f2( void (*f_ptr)(int) );
```

Both `void f_ptr(int)` and `void (*f_ptr)(int)` are identical as function parameter. Now changing the return type of `f_ptr` to *pointer to `void`* (`void *`)

```
int f1( void *f_ptr(int) ); // f_ptr is a function pointer that expects an int type and 
                            // returns a pointer to void    

int f2( void *(*f_ptr)(int) );
```

Name of a function parameter can be removed and therefore above declarations will become

```
int f1( void *(int) );
int f2( void *(*)(int) );
```

Now you can deobfuscate your original function declaration

```
int f( void ( *(int, long) ) (int, long) );
```

as

```
int f( void ( *(*)(int, long) ) (int, long) );
```

and you can place a name for function pointer

```
 int f( void ( *(*func_ptr)(int, long) ) (int, long) );
```

So, `func_ptr` is pointer to a function that expects an `int` and a `long` type parameter and returns a pointer to a function that expects an int and a long type parameter and returns `void`.

Comment: Do you mean "to pointer from void", instead of "to pointer to void"?

Comment: well explained !